# Function (roots which are distinct and real)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Function $f$ is defined by $f(x)=x^{2n}-(p+1)x^2+p,$ where $n$ and $p$ are positive integers. Given that $x-1$ is a factor of $f(x)$ for all values of $p$. When $p=4,x-2$ is a factor of $f(x)$. Find the value of $n$ and factorise $f(x)$ completely.  With the value of $n$ you have obtained, find the set of values of $p$ such that $f(x)+2x^2-2=0$ has roots which are distinct and real.

My attempt:

For first part, I managed to get $n=2$ and $f(x)=x^4-5x^2+4=(x-2)(x+2)(x-1)(x+1)$.

For the second part,

$f(x)+2x^2-2=0$

$x^4-(p+1)x^2+p+2x^2-2=0$

$x^4-(p-1)x^2+p-2=0$

How to proceed from here to find the set of values of $p$ such that $f(x)+2x^2-2=0$ has roots which are distinct and real?

The given solution is $p>2$ and $p\neq3$.

Comment: Hint:Try assuming x^2=t,you will get a quadratic function g(t),apply boundations such as t>0 using vertex point-b/2a>0 and g(0)>0,for D>0 OR D=0 with above conditions,you will get real positive values of t,hence giving real values of x,just make sure to eliminate p for which t=0 is a root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you've corrected the wrong step. Then it's easy to factorize and solve the equation:

$$ (x-1)(x+1)(x^2-(p-2)) = 0 $$

$p-2>0$ to have 4 real solutions and $p-2\ne 1$ to make them distinct.

then $p>2$ and $p\ne 3$.

My first answer here, hope you like it.